# Is hourly paid lecturing a viable route into a permenant lecturing position?

Tags: career-path, early-career

I have struggled to get a permanent lecturing position in the location I want. I am location restricted due to the current COVID 19 situation. My long term goal is to get a permanent lecturing role.

So my question is: Is hourly paid lecturing a viable route to achieve this goal?

A bit of background. I have a PhD and I am on my second postdoc. I have published >20 high quality papers so I am not too worried about my research experience. I just need to get more teaching experience.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you add your country to this?  The answer may vary widely.

Comment: I have relocated back to Ireland. My postdocs were in the USA and UK. Both in highly reputable universities.

Comment: It is extremely risky.

Comment: Do you consider hourly paid teaching alongside your postdoc or as your next step after the postdoc term is over?

Comment: Yes, hourly paid can lead to full time. Depends on the person and the post and the head or manager... The **risk** of not taking any hours can be no money...

Comment: Dmitry: I will be leaving my current postdoc in the UK so this would be a next step.

Comment: Mike: Thanks for your comment. Do you think that the fact that it is an hourly contract role diminish its impact on my CV? I'm wondering if I would be better off with another postdoc in Ireland...

Comment: The tricky part here is “in the location I want”.  Tenure-track positions are few and far between so you often have to take what’s offered, not what you want where you want.

Comment: It can put food on the table while you’re waiting for the global situation to stabilise and let you start looking for work that isn’t location restricted.

Comment: @John Hourly-paid teaching will give you teaching experience. Some teaching experience is helpful if you want a permanent lecturer job. However, most permanent lecturers aren't hired primarily because of their teaching experience - they're hired because of the quality of their research, their profile, and their ability to bring in funding. Not being able to teach would be a problem, but a bit of teaching is generally enough to demonstrate that you're above bar for hiring purposes. Not having papers because you taught too much would be a much bigger obstacle.

Answer (score 4):

I would personally not do this.

1. The world is cruel so why should the institution you are at right now offer you a permanent position when they can get you are a discounted rate?
2. The perspective could change *if* you knew for certain that a position was to open in the near future, but even then I doubt you would just be “gifted” the position: there would likely be a formal competition with no guarantee that you actually get the job.
3. Indeed coming back to 1., if a position is open but the locals know you’re willing to stay, why would they hire you if a position comes open when you’ll still be around anyways?  They could get 2 for the price of 1 by hiring someone else if a position comes open.

Where I work contract lecturers have some sort of protection against outright exploitation (after a few years they have the right to first refusal) but these very very rarely get transformed into permanent positions.

Not that I agree with this way of treating people as human commodities, but then again... it would not be the first time the scenarios above actually happen.